# Extracting Dataverse CRM Data using Dataverse-to-delta Accelerator with Databricks

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I am using the Python code on Databricks located [here](https://github.com/BlueprintTechnologies/blueprint-dataverse-to-delta-accelerator) to extract CRM Data to SQL.Everything appeared to work fine when I executed the code on our CRM platform. However, I noticed that some fields appear to have vanished.

I played around with the following code changing [0] to [1](https://github.com/BlueprintTechnologies/blueprint-dataverse-to-delta-accelerator) or [100]

```
data_schema = generate_schema(input_json=list_data[0])
```

When I changed from [0] to [1](https://github.com/BlueprintTechnologies/blueprint-dataverse-to-delta-accelerator) more fields would appear, and if I changed to [199] even more fields would apppear. However, none of the values produced the total number of fields that should be in the table i.e over 300 fields.

Therefore, could someone take a look at the code and let me know what exactly the code does:

```
data_schema = generate_schema(input_json=list_data[0])
```

Also, what I would need to do get the full list of fields?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how list_data[0] and list_data[1] looks like?

Answer (score -1):

> When I changed from [0] to [1] more fields would appear, and if I changed to [199] even more fields would apppear.

- This might be because the value of `list_data[0]` and the value of `list_data[1]` are not same. Look at the following demonstration. I have used the functions as shown below (modified them a bit).

```
TYPE_MAPPER = {
  bool: BooleanType(),
  str: StringType(), 
  int: LongType(), 
  float: DoubleType()
}

def generate_schema(input_json: dict):

    level = 1
    max_level=None
    stringify_fields=None
    skip_fields=None
    return _populate_struct(input_json, level, max_level, stringify_fields, skip_fields)
  

def _populate_struct(input_json, level, max_level, stringify_fields, skip_fields):
 
  
    if not isinstance(input_json, dict):
        raise ValueError("invalid input JSON")
    if not (isinstance(level, int) and (level > 0)):
        raise ValueError("level must be greater than zero")
    if max_level and not (isinstance(max_level, int) and (max_level >= level)):
        raise ValueError("max_level must be greater than or equal to level (by default, level = 1)")
    
    filled_struct = StructType()
    nullable = True

    for key in input_json.keys():
        if skip_fields and (key in skip_fields):
            continue
        elif (stringify_fields and (key in stringify_fields)) or (max_level and (level >= max_level)):
            filled_struct.add(StructField(key, StringType(), nullable))
        elif isinstance(input_json[key], dict):
            inner_level = level + 1
            inner_struct = _populate_struct(input_json[key], inner_level, max_level, stringify_fields)
            inner_field = StructField(key, inner_struct, nullable)
            filled_struct.add(inner_field)
        elif isinstance(input_json[key], list):
            inner_level = level + 1
            inner_array = _populate_array(input_json[key], inner_level)
            inner_field = StructField(key, inner_array, nullable)
            filled_struct.add(inner_field)
        elif input_json[key] is not None:
            inner_type =  TYPE_MAPPER[type(input_json[key])]
            inner_field = StructField(key, inner_type, nullable)
            filled_struct.add(inner_field)
      
    return filled_struct

def _populate_array(input_array: List,level: int = 1):

  
    if not isinstance(input_array, list):
        raise ValueError("Invalid input array")
    if not (isinstance(level, int) and (level > 0)):
        raise ValueError("level must be greater than zero")

    if len(input_array):
        head = input_array[0]
        inner_level = level + 1
        if isinstance(head, list):
            inner_array = _populate_array(head, inner_level)
            filled_array = ArrayType(inner_array)
        elif isinstance(head, dict):
            inner_struct = _populate_struct(head, inner_level)
            filled_array = ArrayType(inner_struct)
        else:
            inner_type = TYPE_MAPPER[type(head)]
            filled_array = ArrayType(inner_type)
    else:
        default_type = StringType()
        filled_array = ArrayType(default_type)
      
    return filled_array
```

- Now, I have an array of JSON objects called `x`.

```
x = [{'a':'1','b':'2'},{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}]
```

- When I use the `generate_schema` function on x[0] and x[1], the schema returned will be as shown below:

```
print(generate_schema(x[0]))
print(generate_schema(x[1]))
```

[image]

- Now, when I use the schema returned by x[0] and x[1] on the `x` array to build the dataframe (`list_data` in your case), the result would be as shown below:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=x, schema=generate_schema(x[0]))
df1.printSchema()

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=x, schema=generate_schema(x[1]))
df2.printSchema()
```

[image]

- As you can see, the number of fields vary, and this might be the reason for your inconsistency. Check each element of the `list_data` array and debug by comparing whether they have same keys or different keys.

Comment: Hi @Saideep, thanks for reaching out. I discovered that the reason I wasn't getting all the fields is because the code only selects the fields that have all values or fields that have values and nulls. So if I select list_data[2] this will include all fields that have either nulls or  some value where as list_data[9] will only include fields that have a value, but won't include fields that have nulls. I hope this makes sense

Comment: Hey @Patterson, this means that list_data[2] and list_data[9] don't have the same keys and thus when you use generate_schema function on them, they return different schema, just like I have specified in my solution. Clarify if this is the case.